# Query plan estimated row count insanely low despite valid stats

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, indexing

I have a simple query (below) in my data warehouse for which the proper indexes are created.  The query plan always says the estimated row count is around 1 or 2 when it should be around 6,000,000.  I ran sp_updatestats 'resample' and I checked the statistics histogram and it shows 6,000,000 for EQ_ROWS where the DWDateEnd = 12/31/9999, so I'm stumped.  99% of the rows of all tables have a DWDateEnd of 12/31/9999.  If I remove the DWDateEnd filters the estimated row counts become fairly accurate.  It seems to be slowing my queries by causing nested loops where it should be doing hash joins.  Help!

```
SELECT r.OrderID
FROM DWOrders r
JOIN DWOrderStatus rs ON r.OrderID = rs.OrderID AND rs.StatusID = 5 AND rs.ExpiredDate IS NULL 
WHERE rs.StatusTimeStamp BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate AND r.DWDateEnd = '12/31/9999' 
AND rs.DWDateEnd = '12/31/9999'
```

Here's the execution plan.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.1" Build="10.50.4000.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan">
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>          
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="3" StatementEstRows="2.48996" StatementId="3" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" StatementOptmEarlyAbortReason="GoodEnoughPlanFound" StatementSubTreeCost="0.00817222" StatementText="&#xA;SELECT r.OrderID&#xD;&#xA;           FROM DWOrder r&#xD;&#xA;            JOIN DWOrderStatus rs ON r.OrderID = rs.OrderID AND rs.StatusID = 5 AND rs.ExpiredDate IS NULL AND rs.DWDateEnd = '12/31/9999' &#xD;&#xA;           WHERE rs.StatusTimeStamp BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate AND r.DWDateEnd = '12/31/9999' &#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;" StatementType="SELECT" QueryHash="0x24DFCAFA0E610FB3" QueryPlanHash="0x6DD5D50E203E6273">
          <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
          <QueryPlan CachedPlanSize="24" CompileTime="6" CompileCPU="6" CompileMemory="472">
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="11" EstimateCPU="1.0408E-05" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="2.48996" LogicalOp="Inner Join" NodeId="0" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Nested Loops" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00817222">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Database="[EcommArchive]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DWOrder]" Alias="[r]" Column="OrderID" />
              </OutputList>
              <NestedLoops Optimized="false">
                <OuterReferences>
                  <ColumnReference Database="[EcommArchive]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DWOrderStatus]" Alias="[rs]" Column="OrderID" />
                </OuterReferences>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="11" EstimateCPU="0.000159131" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="1.93725" LogicalOp="Index Seek" NodeId="1" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Index Seek" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00328413" TableCardinality="24961700">
                  <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[EcommArchive]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DWOrderStatus]" Alias="[rs]" Column="OrderID" />
                  </OutputList>
                  <IndexScan Ordered="true" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="false" ForceSeek="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false">
                    <DefinedValues>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[EcommArchive]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DWOrderStatus]" Alias="[rs]" Column="OrderID" />
                      </DefinedValue>
                    </DefinedValues>
                    <Object Database="[EcommArchive]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DWOrderStatus]" Index="[IX_DWOrderStatus_DWDateEnd_ExpiredDate_SID_STS_RID]" Alias="[rs]" IndexKind="NonClustered" />
                    <SeekPredicates>
                      <SeekPredicateNew>
                        <SeekKeys>
                          <Prefix ScanType="EQ">
                            <RangeColumns>
                              <ColumnReference Database="[EcommArchive]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DWOrderStatus]" Alias="[rs]" Column="DWDateEnd" />
                              <ColumnReference Database="[EcommArchive]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DWOrderStatus]" Alias="[rs]" Column="ExpiredDate" />
                              <ColumnReference Database="[EcommArchive]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DWOrderStatus]" Alias="[rs]" Column="StatusID" />
                            </RangeColumns>
                            <RangeExpressions>
                              <ScalarOperator ScalarString="'9999-12-31 00:00:00.000'">
                                <Const ConstValue="'9999-12-31 00:00:00.000'" />
                              </ScalarOperator>
                              <ScalarOperator ScalarString="NULL">
                                <Const ConstValue="NULL" />
                              </ScalarOperator>
                              <ScalarOperator ScalarString="(5)">
                                <Const ConstValue="(5)" />
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </RangeExpressions>
                          </Prefix>
                          <StartRange ScanType="GE">
                            <RangeColumns>
                              <ColumnReference Database="[EcommArchive]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DWOrderStatus]" Alias="[rs]" Column="StatusTimeStamp" />
                            </RangeColumns>
                            <RangeExpressions>
                              <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[@StartDate]">
                                <Identifier>
                                  <ColumnReference Column="@StartDate" />
                                </Identifier>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </RangeExpressions>
                          </StartRange>
                          <EndRange ScanType="LE">
                            <RangeColumns>
                              <ColumnReference Database="[EcommArchive]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DWOrderStatus]" Alias="[rs]" Column="StatusTimeStamp" />
                            </RangeColumns>
                            <RangeExpressions>
                              <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[@EndDate]">
                                <Identifier>
                                  <ColumnReference Column="@EndDate" />
                                </Identifier>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </RangeExpressions>
                          </EndRange>
                        </SeekKeys>
                      </SeekPredicateNew>
                    </SeekPredicates>
                  </IndexScan>
                </RelOp>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="11" EstimateCPU="0.000158414" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateRebinds="0.937251" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="1.28531" LogicalOp="Index Seek" NodeId="2" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Index Seek" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00487768" TableCardinality="8048090">
                  <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[EcommArchive]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DWOrder]" Alias="[r]" Column="OrderID" />
                  </OutputList>
                  <IndexScan Ordered="true" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="false" ForceSeek="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false">
                    <DefinedValues>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[EcommArchive]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DWOrder]" Alias="[r]" Column="OrderID" />
                      </DefinedValue>
                    </DefinedValues>
                    <Object Database="[EcommArchive]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DWOrder]" Index="[IX_DWOrder_DWDateEnd]" Alias="[r]" IndexKind="NonClustered" />
                    <SeekPredicates>
                      <SeekPredicateNew>
                        <SeekKeys>
                          <Prefix ScanType="EQ">
                            <RangeColumns>
                              <ColumnReference Database="[EcommArchive]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DWOrder]" Alias="[r]" Column="DWDateEnd" />
                              <ColumnReference Database="[EcommArchive]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DWOrder]" Alias="[r]" Column="OrderID" />
                            </RangeColumns>
                            <RangeExpressions>
                              <ScalarOperator ScalarString="'9999-12-31 00:00:00.000'">
                                <Const ConstValue="'9999-12-31 00:00:00.000'" />
                              </ScalarOperator>
                              <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[EcommArchive].[dbo].[DWOrderStatus].[OrderID] as [rs].[OrderID]">
                                <Identifier>
                                  <ColumnReference Database="[EcommArchive]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DWOrderStatus]" Alias="[rs]" Column="OrderID" />
                                </Identifier>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </RangeExpressions>
                          </Prefix>
                        </SeekKeys>
                      </SeekPredicateNew>
                    </SeekPredicates>
                  </IndexScan>
                </RelOp>
              </NestedLoops>
            </RelOp>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
  </BatchSequence>
</ShowPlanXML>
```

One interesting thing is that if I change = '12/31/9999' to >= '12/31/9999' then it uses a hash join but wants me to change most of my indexes.

Comment: Just to be certain, can you get a query plan with actual vs estimated on it and verify that it has got it wrong?

Comment: Can you post the query plan? Actual preferred.

Comment: I added the query plan to the question, thanks.

Comment: I would look at adding multi column stats e.g. {(DWDateEnd,OrderID),(OrderID,DWDateEnd)} as I believe that the distribution of the values aren't independent.  I had a similar issue with a OrderID and OrderDetailID due to the skew of items in an order over time.  Once you found the combination of stats which help it might be worth checking if filtered stats help where the filter is on DWDateEnd but these have a lot of limitations.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with needing multi-column statistics. It already is using multi-column statistics.

Comment: You have to realize that the estimates are based on all of the columns being referenced and not just DWDateEnd. Additionally, the estimates are not based on the parameter values being passed in for this execution of it. It selected an already existing plan that it deemed was good enough (StatementOptmEarlyAbortReason="GoodEnoughPlanFound").

Comment: In case it helps, clearing the buffer cache did not affect the plan.  And it still said GoodEnoughPlanFound.

Comment: Can you post screenshots of the stats histograms?

Comment: Histograms for two indexes used: http://geekswithblogs.net/influent1/archive/2013/04/12/152675.aspx

Comment: Can you change the WHERE clause to put the "r.DWDateEnd = '12/31/9999' 
AND rs.DWDateEnd = '12/31/9999' " at the beginning?

Comment: As I suspected that makes no difference Michael, the optimizer doesn't care where the filters are.  Any other ideas?

Comment: FYI, I tried the query in SQL Server 2012 and the result is exactly the same.

Comment: Can you post the actual execution plan rather than the estimated execution plan?

Comment: Which table has the 6,000,000 rows for DWDateEnd = 12/31/9999

Comment: Looking at your query plan, SQL is using the index on DWOrderStatus which is then used to lookup on DWORder using the DWDateEnd and the OrderId. If you query just the DWOrderstatus table how may rows do you return?

Comment: DWOrder has 6 million rows, DWOrderStatus has 20 million rows.  The query returns around 5 million rows (even if I just look at DWOrderStatus with the same filters).

Comment: Can you try  running DBCC FREEPROCCACHE (this clears the procedure cache) before running your query make any difference?

Comment: Interesting article here http://erinstellato.com/2012/01/statistics-recompilations/ that says that if you have auto update statistics set to off that query plans will not recompile even if you update the statistics unless they get flushed.

Comment: DBCC FREEPROCCACHE doesn't help, unfortunately I had already tried that.  And AUTO UPDATE STATISTICS is on.  Thanks for trying.

Comment: This looks very similar to this issue here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/ae494f60-1581-49cb-8503-09d5ad90e3d9. This may be fixed by using Trace Flag 4199 as it looks similar to this issue http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920346 which is fixed with this trace flag.

Comment: I actually had tried that and several other trace flags already, no joy.

Comment: Can you please put the create table script and the indexes. I will try to reproduce this. Also what are the row estimates when you remove the DWOrderStatus table?                                         `code`SELECT rs.OrderID
FROM DWOrderStatus 
WHERE rs rs.StatusID = 5 AND rs.ExpiredDate IS NULL 
 AND rs.StatusTimeStamp BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
 AND rs.DWDateEnd = '12/31/9999' `code`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm calling this a bug in SQL Server 2008 R2 (10.50.1400) and SQL Server 2012 (11.0.3000) since nobody has been able to give me an answer that works.  I ended up changing all my queries to use

> DWDateEnd >= '12/31/9999'

(note the addition of Greater Than) since that causes SQL Server to use hash joins instead of nested loops and the queries are WAY faster.

I ended up using a workaround which was adding a persisted computed bit column called DWActive (if DWDateEnd = '12/31/9999' then 1 else 0).  Once I added that column and the corresponding indexes everything was much better.

Answer (score 1):

Please try adding `option (recompile)` to the end of your select statement.

This should force generation of a plan that takes into account the values of your variables.

Another one you could try is `option(optimize for unknown)`.

Comment: Both are reasonable guesses but neither results in any difference in the query plan.

Comment: Have you tried changing `join` to `inner hash join` and seeing if it makes a difference? If the optimizer is not getting there for some reason, you could try forcing the behaviour you need.

Comment: It does force the correct behavior, I forgot to mention that.  The point of this question is that I shouldn't have to force that all the time.  Thanks.